# Remove all whitespaces

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression that searches for a special class and outputs a tag.

```
(?<=<div\ class="value.*?">\s+).*?(?=\s+</div>)
```

The problem is that it leaves whitespaces at the beginning of the tag

**Example:**

```
<div class="value odd">          THIS IS MY TAG                 </div>
```

For now my expression remove the whitespaces only after the tag, but not at the beginning.

**How I can remove it at the beginning?**

I need to get only: `THIS IS MY TAG`

Comment: Why not use an HTML parser like `html.parser` or `lxml`, or a metaparser like BeautifulSoup, to get the tag contents as a string, then just `strip()` that string?

Comment: Rather than `(?<=A\s+).*?(?=\s+B)` use `A\s*(.*?)\s*B`, but since it is HTML, there are better ways to handle this kind of input.

Comment: For example: `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text)`, then `div = soup.find('div', class_=('value', 'odd'))`, then `text = div.text.strip()`.

Comment: I know that this can be done much easier, but in my task I need to use only the regular expression:(

Comment: You regex cannot even be compiled: `sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`.

Comment: https://regexr.com/3ufds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: The link that you provided validates regular expressions for JavaScript and PHP but not Python.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need any look-aheads or look-behinds. A correct regex is:

```
'<div class="value.*?">\s+(.*?)\s+</div>'
```